# Best possible way to find an item from list of variables

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, ubuntu

I have a file named "`demo.cfg`" with lots of variables:

```
$VARIABLE_good="milk bread butter water"
$VARIABLE_bad="beer drugs"
$CONTENT_to_buy="Towel mouse bottle glass pen earphones"
$DUMMYVAR_mixed="drugs water bottle glass"
```

I want to search this entire file for an item "`drugs`", and want to recognize that it belongs to `$VARIABLE_bad`.

I want to assign `$VARIABLE_bad` as `bad` and `$VARIABLE_good` as `good`, `$CONTENT_to_buy` as `to_buy`, `$DUMMYVAR_mixed` as `mixed` etc.

When I search for "`drugs`" in this file, the desired output should be:

```
mixed
bad
```

In the future I might have more variables like those above, so I need a flexible way to solve this problem.

I tried:

`. demo.cfg "drugs"` (This exports all variables)

```
if [[ $(echo $DUMMYVAR_mixed | grep "drugs") ]]; then echo "mixed"; fi
if [[ $(echo $DUMMYVAR_to_buy | grep "drugs") ]]; then echo "to_buy"; fi
if [[ $(echo $VARIABLE_bad | grep "drugs") ]]; then echo "bad"; fi
if [[ $(echo $VARIABLE_good | grep "drugs") ]]; then echo "good"; fi
```

But this looks lengthy and doesn't seem flexible. Any better solutions?

Comment: Have you considered using a python script? They are normally shorter for these kind of things.

Comment: No.. I need to write only in bash. Since this script links with other script. @katutxakurra

Comment: Basically i need to fetch the part as you said and append list and show them @don_crissti

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just calls for `awk`. The trivial case where there's only one `=` on the line:

```
awk -vpat=drugs -F= '$2 ~ pat {gsub(/^\$[A-Z]+_/, "", $1); print $1; }' demo.cfg
```

`-vpat=...` sets a variable used in the match: `-F=` separates the fields on the `=`, `$2 ~` matches on the second field and `gsub` replaces the initial part of the first field with an empty string. Then the first field `$1` is printed. (I assumed the initial part only has uppercase letters before the underscore.)

---

If you can have equal signs in the value, we could search for an equal sign followed by the keyword from the whole line, like this:

```
awk -vpat=drugs -F= '$0 ~ ("=.*" pat) {gsub(/^\$[A-Z]+_/, "", $1); print $1; }' demo.cfg
```

Or just split the two parts manually, but that's a bit longer.

---

Note that if `demo.cfg` contains assigments like `$VARIABLE_good="milk bread butter water"`, with the dollar sign, sourcing it in the shell won't work:

```
$ . demo.cfg
-bash: =milk bread butter water: command not found
```

Assigments take just the name of the variable, The dollar sign is only used when expanding the variable.

Comment: Thanks @ikkachu.. yes, by mistake i wrote `$` sign. Ideally, it is shouldnt be there.. This answer looks a better one. Thanks

Comment: I knew there was an `awk` oneliner just waiting out there. Good job (upvoted)!

Comment: @ikkachu.. How do i include this demo.cfg as an external file and integrate awk command in a script. ? I tried something like `source demo.cfg` in script. but doesnt seems to work!!

Comment: That assumes the value of the variable doesn't contain `=`.

Comment: True, added another version to support multiple `=`s.

Comment: @Kasino, mm, I'm not sure what you mean. `source foo` runs the contents of `foo` as a shell script, in the current shell. You should be able to run that `awk` script as part of a shell script, and replace the pattern and filename with shell variables if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

If that is how all your variables look, you could use `grep` and `sed` together like this:

```
cat demo.cfg 
$VARIABLE_good="milk bread butter water"
$VARIABLE_bad="beer drugs"
$CONTENT_to_buy="Towel mouse bottle glass pen earphones"
$DUMMYVAR_mixed="drugs water bottle glass"


grep drugs demo.cfg | sed -r 's/.*_([a-z].*)=.*/\1/'
bad
mixed
```

The first grep simply searches for the word `drugs`, that line is then piped to `sed` with this expression:

`.*_` = delete any character up until the first underscore.
`([a-z].*)=` = save lowercase letters until the = sign
`.*` = delete the rest of the string
`\1` = replace with saved expression

Comment: The best approach here imo is to use `sed` in quiet mode and attempt to replace the entire line with just the needed part but only on lines matching `drugs` and use the `p` flag with `s` (print only when replacing) e.g.: `sed -nE 's/^[[:upper:]]+_(.*)=.*drugs.*/\1/p' demo.cfg` (the regex was tailored per OPs comment on the other answer)

Comment: @don_crissti True, that would be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `sed` here:

```
$ sed -n 's/^$[^_=]*_\([^=]*\)=.*drugs.*/\1/p' < file
bad
mixed
```

`-n` in combination with the `s` command's `p` flag allows to print only the result of successful substitutions.

With GNU `grep`:

```
$ grep -Po '^[^=]*?_\K.*?(?==.*drugs)' < file
bad
mixed
```

If you want to make `drugs` a *variable*, then you could use:

```
string=drugs
grep -Po "^[^=]*?_\K.*?(?==.*$string)" < file
```

However note that if `$string` contains special characters in regular expression, in that case (with `-P`), Perl compatible regular expressions, then they  would have to be escaped (for instance, with `string="..."` that would match on values that contain at least 3 characters instead of values that contain `...`). The equivalent would be even worse in `sed` or `awk` as failing to escape them would introduce a command injection vulnerability (if the content of `$string` is not totally under your control).

With `awk`, you could do:

```
export STRING=drugs
awk -F = '(n = index($0, "=")) && \
          (m = index($0, "_")) < n && \
          index(substr($0, n+1), ENVIRON["STRING"]) {
            print substr($0, m + 1, n - m - 1)
          }' < file
```

Comment: I want to pass "drugs" as a variable to a script. how can i pass variable inside sed or grep ?